# How do I check if something entered in python is the same as something on a csv file

Tags: python, csv, input

I am trying to make a program to see if the username and password entered into a python program is the same as the username and password stored in a csv file.

```
logorsign = input("""Choose one:
1. Log in
2. Sign up
3. Quit
""")
print("")

if logorsign == "1":           
    Netflix_CSV = csv.reader(open("Netflix Task.csv", "rt"))       
    first_Line = next(Netflix_CSV)
    checkuser = input("Enter Username: ")
    print("")
    checkpasw = input("Enter Password: ")
    for row in Netflix_CSV:
        if row[0]  == checkuser:
            print(watched_films)
```

This, above, is the code so far.

Please help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: please have a lookt at pandas, which would improve your queries somewaht

Answer (score 0):

The best data structure to use here is a dictionary:

```
user_passwords = dict()
user_films = dict()
user_logged_in = False

given_username = input('Enter Username: ')
print('')
given_password = input('Enter Password: ')
print('')

with open('Netflix Task.csv', 'r') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    reader.next()   # Skip the header line
    for line in reader:
        username, password, watched_films = line
        user_passwords[username] = password
        user_films[username] = watched_films

if user_passwords.get(given_username, False) == given_password:
    print('login successful')
    user_logged_in = True
else:
    print('Bad username/password')
```

Then, to access the user's films:

```
users_films = user_films[username]
```

Comment: I got this error:                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Task 2.py", line 28, in <module>
    with csv.reader(open('Netflix Task.csv', 'rt')) as fh:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: Made changes to the file handler